# junit 5.10.0: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'java.lang.ClassLoader org.junit.platform.commons.util.ClassLoaderUtils.getClassLoader(java.lang.Class)'

Tags: spring-boot, junit5, spring-boot-3

I am moving from spring boot 2.6.6 to 3.1.4

In 3.1.4 setup I am using below test artifacts.

The current versions are -
Spring Boot 3.1.4
JUNIT = 5.10.0
MOCKITO = 5.6.0
COMMONS_IO = 2.11.0

The below tests were working perfectly with version -
Spring Boot 2.6.6
JUNIT = 5.8.2
MOCKITO = 4.2.0
COMMONS_IO = 2.11.0

My test is as below -

```
private static Stream<Arguments> expiresAt() {
  return Stream.of(
      Arguments.of(Instant.ofEpochSecond(0), true),
      Arguments.of(Instant.ofEpochSecond(9), true),
      Arguments.of(Instant.ofEpochSecond(10), false),
      Arguments.of(Instant.ofEpochSecond(11), false),
      Arguments.of(Instant.ofEpochSecond(20), false)
  );
}

@DisplayName("should determine if token has expired")
@ParameterizedTest
@MethodSource("expiresAt")
void shouldDetermineIfTokenHasExpired(Instant expiresAt, boolean expected) {
  // given:
  var response = SolumAuthTokenResponse.builder()
      .responseMessage(ResponseMessage.builder().expiresAt(expiresAt).build())
      .build();
  // when:
  var actual = subject.hasExpired(response);
  // then:
  Assertions.assertEquals(expected, actual);
}
```

The error I am facing is -

```
java.lang.ClassLoader org.junit.platform.commons.util.ClassLoaderUtils.getClassLoader(java.lang.Class)'
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'java.lang.ClassLoader org.junit.platform.commons.util.ClassLoaderUtils.getClassLoader(java.lang.Class)'
    at org.junit.jupiter.params.provider.MethodArgumentsProvider.findFactoryMethodByFullyQualifiedName(MethodArgumentsProvider.java:114)
    at org.junit.jupiter.params.provider.MethodArgumentsProvider.findFactoryMethod(MethodArgumentsProvider.java:77)
    at org.junit.jupiter.params.provider.MethodArgumentsProvider.lambda$provideArguments$1(MethodArgumentsProvider.java:53)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:197)
    at java.base/java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:992)
    ...
    at worker.org.gradle.process.internal.worker.GradleWorkerMain.run(GradleWorkerMain.java:69)
    at worker.org.gradle.process.internal.worker.GradleWorkerMain.main(GradleWorkerMain.java:74)
    Suppressed: org.junit.platform.commons.PreconditionViolationException: Configuration error: You must configure at least one set of arguments for this @ParameterizedTest
        at org.junit.platform.commons.util.Preconditions.condition(Preconditions.java:299)
        at org.junit.jupiter.params.ParameterizedTestExtension.lambda$provideTestTemplateInvocationContexts$5(ParameterizedTestExtension.java:98)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.close(AbstractPipeline.java:323)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$7$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:273)
        ... 70 more
```

How to solve this? I did look up on internet but had no luck.

Comment: Why don’t you simply set the junit version to whatever was working for you?

Comment: there are other tests that fail if i use the earlier junit version of 5.8.2. ...lol

Comment: @samshers could you please show your build file (e.g. `pom.xml`)?

Comment: @beatngu13 - I could fix it..  seems junit 5.9.3 is compatible with spring boot 3.1.x, using this junit version solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I could fix it..  seems junit `5.9.3` (but not 5.10.0) is compatible with spring boot 3.1.x, using this junit version solved the issue.